# Linq Join issue in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am so very new to c# and am learning as I go...

I have two tables, Blog and BlogCategories.  The Blog table has an id that references the category in BlogCategories.

I am having an issue with the syntax on the join:

```
var categories = new List<BlogCategory>();

        if (model.BlogCategoryId.HasValue)
        {
            var query =
                   from category in categories
                   join blog in model on category.Id equals model.BlogCategoryId
                   select new { BlogCategory = category.Name };

        }
```

The issue is that it doesn't like the join and get :

```
Error   CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... PHP is not a big boy language, this is.

Quick table structure
BlogPosts table:
Id,
BlogCategory,
Title,
Content

BlogCategories:
Id,
CategoryName

EDIT:
Solution seems like it would work but error somewhere:

```
 var blogPosts = PopulateBlogPosts();

        if (model.BlogCategoryId.HasValue)
        {
            var blogPostCategories = PopulateBlogCategories();

            blogPosts = blogPostCategories.Where(c => c.Id == model.BlogCategoryId).Single(); 
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve? A list of BlogCategory objects?

Comment: Just the blog category where the id on the blog post matches.  I dont know why i have the Product = prod.Name in there....

Comment: So you just want a single `BlogCategory`? `BlogCategoryId` is the primary key of `BlogCategory`?

Comment: Post the Structure of the Two Models Blog and BlogCategories

Comment: correct.  is LINQ not the proper way at this point?  I am in the controller but the way it is done, they are just returning the blog model.  So I am trying to just append this category onto the model returned to the view.

Comment: What are the types of `category.Id` & `model.BlogCategoryId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `categories` is an `IEnumerable<BlogCategory>`.

```
var category = categories.Single(c => c.Id == model.BlogCategoryId);
```

This [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method asserts you're only expecting one object to match, and it allows you to filter. It will throw an exception if there is anything other than one category that meets the filter criteria. It's a shorter form of this:

```
var category = categories.Where(c => c.Id == model.BlogCategoryId).Single();
```

Comment: What if categories is an IQueryable?

Comment: @echo [that inherits from IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I am not understanding this simple issue I am having...  Your solution seems like it would work.  Code edits in original post.

Comment: So what's not working? Is it giving an error? What is it not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'BLAHBLAH.Core.Models.BlogCategory' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<BLAHBLAH.Core.Models.BlogPost>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) BLAHBLAHC:\Users\echoBr00tal\Source\Workspaces\Onveos\Development\BLAHBLAH\Areas\Admin\Controllers\BlogController.cs 49 Active

Comment: PopulateBlogCategories is a method: private IQueryable<BlogCategory>PopulateBlogCategories

Comment: You said you want to return a `BlogCategory`. My code does that. However, your error indicates it's expecting a `BlogPost`.